# Does overriding a Subscription automatically unsubscribes the previous value?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have the following subscription in an angular application:

```
  private _sub: Subscription;
```

On initialization I subscribe to a firebase get function:

```
this._sub = this.service.get('database1').subscribe(
   data => {
      this.ListOfData = data;
   }
);
```

But depending on user input I change `database1` to other collections, or use a different method instead of `get()`.

When I override `_sub` will the previous stream get automatically unsubcribed, or do I have to manually do it before overriding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: No it doesn't...I'll share the details on why

Whenever `.subscribe()` is called, [a new instance of a `Subscription` is created](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subscription) that holds resources that listen to the execution of the Observable. If you call `.subscribe()` and do not call `.unsubscribe()`, your Subscription is still utilizing resources. In some cases (depending on the logic associated to the Observable/Subject) it can result in unexpected behavior in your application and it can impact performance. This is why the best practice is to call `.unsubscribe()` on your `Subscription` when you are done with it.

There are also functions called [RxJS operators](https://rxjs.dev/guide/operators#rxjs-operators) that can help you to manage your subscriptions by automatically unsubscribing based on certain criteria.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to unsubscribe. Sometimes they stay like sleeper cells to damage your application performance. Best practice is unsubscribe.

Comment: why was this downvot3d?